# How can I get the markup's core extension to automatically close the text area it creates?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

The MarkupsCore extension automatically creates a text area when you click that you enter text into. Now, I automatically insert text into this text area, but cannot find out how to close it programatically. After going through the source a little bit, it seemed like the text area was a little bit custom as I saw there were some custom implementations of the backspace button, etc. So, I assumed there was a different event.

It seems to happen when you focus out of the element, but that event didn't seem to do it either. In version 3 (or maybe it was earlier, I can't remember), you used to press the enter key. Now you just focus out.

So, what event needs to be fired in order to tell the extension to close the text area and create the markup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following...

Using the 'markupscore' object, send a 'mouse down' event with 'target:null' like this...

```
markupscoreExt = viewer.getExtension("Autodesk.Viewing.MarkupsCore")
markupscoreExt.onMouseDown({target:null})
```

As you are in the middle of typing some text, you can trigger the mouse down event to complete the text.

Let me know if that helps.

Cheers
Michael